# How to render links generated dynamically from JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, object

To display links in my rendered JSON, I want them as value in the name/value pair.

The function below takes a valid JSON as a parameter and should return JSON with their values converted to anchor tags.

The input JSON is

```
{"@context":"/api/contexts/EntryPoint.jsonld","@id":"/api","@type":"EntryPoint","AnomalyCollection":"/api/AnomalyCollection","CommandCollection":"/api/CommandCollection","ControllerLogCollection":"/api/ControllerLogCollection","DroneCollection":"/api/DroneCollection","DroneLogCollection":"/api/DroneLogCollection","HttpApiLogCollection":"/api/HttpApiLogCollection","Location":"/api/Location","MessageCollection":"/api/MessageCollection","dsCollection":"/api/dsCollection"}
```

`{"k": "v"}` should get changed to `{"k": <a href="#">v</a>}`

I understand that the changed value would not be a valid JSON, then what is the way out?

```
function makeEditable(data) {
  for (var property in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      var tag = $('<a href=#>' + data[property] + '</a>');
      data[property] = tag;
    }
  }
  return data;

}
```

The function above instead of giving links, gives the below render.

```
{
  @context : {
  0 :  "http://localhost:5000/#"
 },
   @id : {
   0 :  "http://localhost:5000/#"
 },
   @type : {
   0 :  "http://localhost:5000/#"
 }
}
```

What I want is a render similar to this

[image: JSON]

Comment: Can we see the original JSON please?

Comment: @JackBashford It's `{"k": "v"}` in the question.

Comment: The above method would not generate the given output. It would contain a jQuery object as the value. Please create a runnable of your issue.

Comment: I have edited the question for the original JSON, although it is hardly related to the beahviour

Comment: What you're seeing is how jQuery objects look when you convert them to JSON.

Comment: Your code is fine, the problem is just with how you're viewing the result.

Comment: What do I do then? I want links instead of jQuery object representations in the DOM

Comment: It will work correctly when you append the objects to the DOM.

Comment: If you do `$("#someDIV").append(data["@id"]);` you'll see the link.

Comment: Your "`{"k": "v"}` should get changed to`{"k": <a href="#">v</a>}`" appears fictitious, put your actual desired output in there to avoid confusion.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss His problem now appears to be that he does want to store an anchor tag as a value. Which indeed is fictitious.

Comment: I have added an image to avoid confusion

Comment: I apologize, I should have added the image along with the question before.

Comment: So elaborate on why you're trying to add an anchor tag or in this instance modify the JSON object at all since the original JSON matches your desired output?

Comment: @Adriani6 I want the uri in the JSON to be inline editable and hence I am using https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/ which essentially requires the text must have an achor tag to enable the `editable()` method to be invoked

Comment: Your input does not in any way match the image of output, voting to close as unclear what you are asking as it is really even more unclear now.

Comment: I will try my best again. The input JSON contains a text(a URI). This URI should be converted to an anchor tag with the text as the URI.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest to not manipulate your data (JSON) and do the DOM implementation on your HTML or template that you're using.

In case you insist on following your approach: don't wrapper your anchor tag by jQuery just write it as a string. something like `<a href=#>${data[property]}</a>`

Comment: Tried that too.But then it gets rendered just as a string, not as a link.

Comment: check this one out > [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pourya7/zpk5fgye/14)

Comment: This doesn't even has anchor tags

Answer (score 0):

You're meant to make it a string, not a anchor, otherwise (because jQuery) it'll make `data[property]` equal to the URL you get directed to when you click on the anchor, because this:

```
<a href=#>v</a>
```

Was turned into this:

```
http://localhost:5000/#
```

Which is where you'd get directed to if you'd click on the link. Try using a simple template literal instead (it's also smaller and simpler than concatenating strings):

```
function makeEditable(data) {
  for (var property in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      var tag = `<a href="3">${data]property]}</a>`;
      data[property] = tag;
    }
  }
  return data;
}
```

Comment: @invinciblycool That's what it's meant to render as - an anchor tag. You can't make it *not* a string without making it *not* an anchor tag, so this is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that modifying JSON would not work and instead decided to append to the div directly.

This was the function after modification:

```
function makeEditable(data) {
  var fdata={};
  for (var property in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      $("#vocab-json").append('<b>'+property+'</b>'+'<a href="#" id="uri">'+data[property]+'</a><br>');
    }
  }
  return fdata;
}
```